# Overspaced paragraphs

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}%, oneside


\begin{document}
\chapter{Current Approach}\label{chap:background}

\pagebreak

\section{Approximation}
Nunc accumsan iaculis odio, vel pretium neque condimentum non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In et facilisis arcu. Vestibulum non massa augue. Proin lobortis dignissim velit, quis pulvinar ipsum vestibulum vel. Nulla vitae ipsum ante. Maecenas eu arcu at elit luctus dictum nec eget magna. Vivamus eu faucibus eros. \\


Nunc accumsan iaculis odio, vel pretium neque condimentum non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In et facilisis arcu. Vestibulum non massa augue. Proin lobortis dignissim velit, quis pulvinar ipsum vestibulum vel. Nulla vitae ipsum ante. Maecenas eu arcu at elit luctus dictum nec eget magna. Vivamus.\\

Nunc accumsan iaculis odio, vel pretium neque condimentum non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In et facilisis arcu.\\

Nunc accumsan iaculis odio, vel pretium neque condimentum non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos m.\\

The algorithm works as shown in Figure 1.2.

\pagebreak

\section{Exact algorithm}
previously, generated a depth first tree for every instance, now it is generated for only one instance

optimization using bit vectors

problem with the search tree being too huge (State the complexity)

Why, contrary to X's solution, iterative deepening might not be used in this approach

\end{document}
```

The above code generates a 3 page document, one of which is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing between the paragraphs is enormous. Now my question is, what might be the cause of such a problem, and what could be a possible solution?

Comment: Try inserting the expression `\raggedbottom` in the preamble.

Comment: Replace `\pagebreak` with `\newpage` or `\clearpage`.